# Sql shows every query instead of specific one

Tags: php, mysql

Problem is :

`$type` = my `r_areal` variable

```
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM reservation where r_areal IN ('".$type."') and '".$cid."' between r_start and r_ende 
            or where r_areal IN ('".$type."') '".$cod."' between r_start and r_ende 
            or where r_areal IN ('".$type."') '".$cid."'<= r_start AND '".$cod."' >= r_ende


            ";
```

So this is my php query for sql. It works, but it shows me every sql rows for every `$type` in my db. But it should instead only show all rows for f.e. the parameter B. I know, that one problem is that the `where r_areal IN ('".$type."')` is only accepted once. But if I remove the second and third one, it shows me all rows for all `$type`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you need to use parenthesis, otherwise you have mixture of AND and OR

Comment: this is horrendously vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please learn to use parameterised queries, otherwise your data can easily be corrupted, deleted or stolen. http://bobby-tables.com/ explains the issues (humourosly, but straightforwardly) and also has some examples, including in PHP, of how to include variables in your query safely.

Comment: Does this code actually run?  I see multiple `WHERE` in this statement.  That definitely won't run.

Comment: It does run, but it shows me every column. It simply ignores the 2nd and 3rd `where` statement

Comment: It kind of looks like all those different where clauses are trying to do the same thing. Can you explain in more detail what this is supposed to select?

Comment: And what are `$cid` and `$cod`?

Comment: @CodeNewb If it runs, you must have copied it wrong in the question. There's no way that `or where` can possibly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parenthesis to separate AND and OR conditions.

```
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM reservation 
    WHERE (r_areal IN ('".$type."') AND '".$cid."' BETWEEN r_start AND r_ende) 
            OR  (r_areal IN ('".$type."') '".$cod."' BETWEEN r_start AND r_ende)
            OR (r_areal IN ('".$type."') '".$cid."'<= r_start AND '".$cod."' >= r_ende)
            ";
```